# Make small design changes on store view

Tags: magento-1.9, css, store-view

I'm trying to make a few small design changes in my second store view. I was wondering if there is an easy way to do this - without duplicating the theme or stylesheets, example:
I want to change the colour of navigation wrap in store view /trade - I thought I could just run down the css and add these selectors:

```
.navwrap[href*="/trade/"] {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

This didn't work! Any suggestions?

(Magento 1.9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a theme that inherits from your existing theme and assign that to your store view, then you only need to add the CSS on top of your other theme rather than duplicating any code.

I don't have enough time to give you an example other than this small snippet but [this link](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2015/06/magento-1-9-multiple-theme-inheritance/) will hopefully give you some guidance.

This is how to create a child theme:

1. Create a theme “child” that extends from another theme “premium_template”
2. Within the child folder create `etc/theme.xml`
3. Populate it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>your_package/your_parent_theme</parent>
</theme>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have read through the link - it looks like this will work!

Comment: The person who added the incorrect answer has down-voted us both xD

Comment: Bitter guy! Thank again for your answer!